# Method withCount does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using **laravel 5.4**
so i'm trying to count number of relations between two models "Person" and "Permanance"
so this is how it is called in my controller
`$persons = Person::all()->withCount('Permanance')->get();`
and this is the error i'm getting

(1/1) BadMethodCallException

Method withCount does not exist.
in Macroable.php line 74
at Collection->__call('withCount', array('Permanance'))in PermanancesController.php line 41

Answer (score 0):

You should use directly as a static mehtod `withCount` without the `all()` method, as described here in the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

```
$posts = Post::withCount('comments')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Please call like below,

$persons = Person::withCount('Permanance')->get();